# Declaring a class - shared instance or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am wondering is my class shared across instances:
I have a route, for example:

> /student/:id

That route activates this controller (shortened version):

```
module.exports = RecalculateStudents;

const recalculateActiveStudents = require('../../DataModifier/ActiveStudents');

class StudentCalculator extends AbstractStudentController {    

    startApi(request, context) {

        //Is Students shared accross the calls, or it is single instance?
        let Students = recalculateActiveStudents.recalculateStudentTimes(ctx);

        //rest of the code is here
    }
}

module.exports = RecalculateStudents;
```

And then I have the RecalculateStudents class (used in controller):

```
'use strict';

class StudentCalculator {

    constructor() {
        this.startPoint = null;
        this.finalProductStatus = null;
    }

    recalculateStudentTimes(ctx) {

        this.startGrades = ctx.currentGrades;
        this.finalStudentGrades = ctx.finalGrades;

        this.calculateActivities(this.startGrades)
    }

    calculateActivities() {        
        //
    }       
}

module.exports = new StudentCalculator();
```

I have removed other methods from those two classes to preserve clarity.

My question is:
In the controller, I have this line of code:

```
let Students = recalculateActiveStudents.recalculateStudentTimes(ctx);
```

And inside that class I have a constructor with two variables, which I need (simple variable holders). Assume, another call is made, is the Students going to be unique, or shared between the calls?

My concern is if there are several calls (different users) that those variables will be mixed?

My understanding is that variables will not be shared, as they are exported using the keyword new.

Comment: *Modules* are shared. Variables inside functions are not, but that doesn't matter - `const recalculateActiveStudents` is a constant outside of your class anyway, which makes it shared amongst all instances.

Comment: *Never* export a `new Anything`. If you wanted a singleton module object, you shouldn't have used class syntax; If you wanted a class, you should export the constructor.

Comment: Can you please provide more information regarding: never export a new? My main objective is to have unique instance of my Students

Comment: By "unique instance", do you mean that you want to have only a single instance in your whole application?

Comment: In the class, I have a constructor with two variables. I would need it to NOT to be shared across instance. For example, controller is hit by StudentA, and StudentB. I would like those two variables in constructor to be unique, with their own data respectively.

Comment: Yes, those *properties* are not shared across instances, your problem is that you are only instantiating a single one.

Comment: I do see that I am not understanding properly. Please forgive my questions, I would like to understand this. What do you mean that I am instantiating only one? Code flow is: route->controller->class that does some work

Comment: `module.exports = new StudentCalculator();` is creating a single, global instance that is shared by your whole program. Notice that `require` does not re-execute modules

Comment: I see. So if I were to use module.exports = StudentCalculator, and instantiate it inside my controller, then it would be unique?

Comment: Yes, then each controller would get its own calculator.

Answer (score 2):

The variables will indeed be unique. `this` references whatever is using it and only that. (If I'm understanding your question right). If you did want to share the a variable in an instance across all the instances, you'd have to use its `prototype`. However you want to export the class and create new instances. **Not** export an instance of the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique", that there is only a singe one or that each call has its own?

Comment: Each call has its own. @Bergi

Comment: Then the answer is wrong. There is only a single `recalculateActiveStudents` instance in the OPs code

Comment: @Bergi My answer isn't exactly wrong. However, the op's method wouldn't  work for what he's trying to do. I've edited my answer to point that out.